# Allowing the use of the token `class` as a named parameter in a method signature

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I have a python file filled with functions like `h1` and `img` and `strong` for use styling text. Each of these functions are defined as follows:

```
def _wrapTag(tag, text, **attributes):
    out = _createTag(tag, **attributes)
    out += text
    out += "</" + tag + ">"
    return out

def _createTag(tag, **attributes):
    out = "<" + tag
    if attributes:
        for attr, value in attributes:
            out += " " + attr + "=\"" + value + "\""
    out += ">"
    return out

def h2(text, **attributes):
    return _wrapTag("h2", text, **attributes)
```

In an ideal world, to create a `div` with the class `modal`, I would call `div(content, class="modal")` however `class` is a restricted keyword. Is there any way to bypass this without adding a special case to `_createTag`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) standard way of handling that is to add a trailing underscore:

- single_trailing_underscore_: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword, e.g.

`Tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')`

That's a common workaround and won't surprise anyone. You could implement that in your code like:

```
def _createTag(tag, **attributes):
    out = "<" + tag
    if attributes:
        for attr, value in attributes.items():
            out += " " + attr.rstrip('_') + "=\"" + value + "\""
    out += ">"
    return out
```

so that it automatically removes the extra underscore from any and all attributes. Then you could call:

```
>>> h2('contents', class_='myh2tag', id_='contenttag')
'<h2 class="myh2tag" id="contenttag">contents</h2>'
```

and work around two separate Python namespace conflicts without handling either of them as a special case.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Python keywords can't be used as identifiers and that's that.  The usual solution in these kinds of things is to use `class_` as the name.  It requires special casing, but there's no way around it.

Comment: Eh, I had the feeling that might be true. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
_createTag(tag, **{"class": 1})
```

Using this syntax you can pass in anything to **attributes. No code change in the functions is necessary.